# How t solve when Scrapy returns garbled text

Tags: python, scrapy, character-encoding

I am using `scrapy`

What I have done is like this

```
import scrapy
class UtamapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'utamap'
    allowed_domains = ['www.utamap.com']
    def start_requests(self):

        urls = ['https://www.utamap.com/phpflash/flashfalsephp.php?unum=37776']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.encoding) # it shows euc_jp
        print(response.text)
        print(response.encode('UTF-8')) #it returns maybe byte code
```

There comes the garbled text like  `綉���鴻��������茵`

`print(response.encoding)` shows `euc_jp`, however encode() doesn't work in this case.

How can I solve ??

Comment: Assuming `response.text` comes from the requests package, it's already decoded, so `print(response.text)` should work.  If not, you need to provide the response headers and `request.content`.

Comment: I still can't run it. It still has `self` and needs a class. Also, none of these methods are ever called. Imports are missing. It's not a [mre] yet

Comment: SOrry, I updated again. with scrapy you can run `scrapy crawl utamap`

Answer (score 0):

Not using response.text but use response.body

```
def parse(self, response):
    print(response.encoding) # it shows euc_jp
    print(response.body.decode('UTF-8'))
```

it works.